# DNS servers not assigned by DHCP

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-xp, windows-vista, ip, dhcp

I got working domain with DHCP, DNS servers installed and firewall ZyWall 5 which resolves names to internet. In DHCP server configuration I've set also static IP address of server as a primary DNS server but when I try to renew IP address on Windows XP clients logged to domain there is only ZyWall IP address listed in DNS servers. This makes internet connection working but I can't login into domain on any computer vith Vista. Even with profiles which are already working well with Windows XP. And also when I try to check out comunication with nslookup, it also tries to ping ZyWall and also fails to do so as there is only Request timed out.

Answer (score 2):

Your ZyWall thing probably has it's own embedded DHCP server which is interfering with your Domain DNS.  Disable that and you're done.

Comment: DHCP server was already disabled on firewall but I've realized, that I did stupid mistake. I set DNS servers in DHCP settings for whole server but not for IP address pool. This was my first server configuration ever so I'm learning all the time. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

And also when I try to check out comunication with nslookup, it also tries to ping ZyWall and also fails to do so as there is only Request timed out.

Comment: Please update your original question. Do not post additional information as answer. This is not a forum.

Comment: Cmon guys -- dont knock down his update because he didn't understand the protcol.  +1 to even it out a little.

Comment: I didn't downvote his own answer. Since it's at -1 right now, I'll upvote it to 0.